# How to extract body from a raw HTTP request?

Tags: c#, .net, http, tcplistener

In my application, I get a raw HTTP request via TcpListener and TcpClient classes. I need to extract the request body. How would you do that? I'm thinking about the fastest way. I don't need headers, just the body.

I can't use HttpListener because of the permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a raw HTML request, the headers and body will be separated by a blank line.

```
Header1: stuff
Header2: More stuff

Body begins here
```

So it should be as simple as scanning for a blank line.